# Table view doesn't retain the selected values after scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

In my app, inorder to select preferences I created a custom cell with switch and load it in a table. There are 21 categories to select. My problem is when I ON the switches in the first section and scroll down and came back ,the switches are OFF. I think the problem is with reuse identifier. But I made it nil and yet no luck. I need to save the selected preferences in database and display it. Please help me in keeping the selected values intact. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing code no one can help. Post some code if you have a code logic issue and how and where you want to keep things

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the switches' value in an array so you can set them the next time `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called. The cells are recycled so offscreen cells will lose their content if you don't save their value.

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method, when scrolls reuse identifier calls and refresh all cells.

Try compare like this ( I am writing like an algoritm, implement this in cellForRowAtIndexPath method).

if( cell in switch on)
[switch setSender:on]
else
 [switch setSender:off];